# Glfw hidden mouse cursor showing if move too fast

Tags: opengl, glfw

I am trying to create a camera class for my game in using glfw and opengl. The glfw command I am using to hide my cursor is `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED).` The problem is that if I am not in full screen and I move my mouse extremely fast to one side, I can manage to escape the window and the mouse cursor will show up. This almost seem to happen because the mouse is not being centered fast enough by the glfw itself so you can go out. How do I fix this problem so that mouse cursor will always stay in the window regardless of how fast I am moving it?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Because GLFW already does that on Windows at least.

Comment: II am using window. However, doesn't minecraft uses glfw because the lwjgl uses glfw as a window. However, minecraft doesn't run into this problem. So what exactly are they doing different. I tried to set my cursor to the center explicitly with glfwSetCursorPos() but it still have the problem.

Comment: No using `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED)` in the newest version of GLFW, should be enough. I just verified this on Windows 10.

Comment: I actually tested it multiple time and every time, if I move my mouse fast enough the cursor appears. I am also running window 10. That is weird.

Comment: Why does this is not a problem for game like minecraft because I launched it and everything work. Hence I feel as though there is something that minecraft is doing that I am not.

Comment: Again, I told you what you're doing is how it's done. So you must be doing something else, or not using the newest GLFW version.